# Conditional formatting in Excel, not blank and less than for whole column?

Tags: excel-formula

I am making a spreadsheet to track my blood sugars, yes I'm diabetic, I want several columns to to be able to highlight red if the number is less than 70. Easy I thought but the problem is when I do that all of the blank ones highlight red. In an ideal world and if it were up to my doctor there wouldn't be any "blank" cells, but I'm not perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Highlight the range you want to apply the formatting to. Then we need to write a formula as if we were just writing it for the first cell of the range. Let's say your range is D:G. Add a new conditional format (Home --> Conditional Formatting --> New Rule) and select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format as shown below. Then we need to apply the following conditional format. This will highlight cell D1 if and only if D1 does not equal an empty text string AND D1 < 70. **Make sure you delete your old conditional format.**

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using less than, use format if value in between 1 and 70. This will rule out all blank cells.